# Saving variables of a DialogFragment on rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-recyclerview

I have a DialogFragment, which holds a RecyclerView.
To populate the recyclerview, I want to give it a HashSet, and populate items inside that RecyclerView.

Problem is, that since there's no `onSaveInstanceState` -> `onRestoreInstanceState`, I cannot save it regularly.

I've seenn posts about `setRetainInstance(true)`, but it does not save my RecyclerView state.

That is my code:

```
package giorag.dailytimer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by GioraPC on 01/03/2016.
 */
public class TeamNamesEditDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText personName;
    private RecyclerView namesList;
    private ImageButton addName;
    private TeamNamesAdapter adapter;

    public TeamNamesEditDialog() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
            getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_names, container);
        personName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.team_names_new_name);
        namesList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.team_names_list);
        namesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        addName = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.team_names_add_name);

        getDialog().setTitle("Update team");

        adapter = new TeamNamesAdapter(null);

        namesList.setAdapter(adapter);
        namesList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));
        addName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.addName(personName.getText().toString());
                personName.setText("");
            }
        });

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback =
                new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(namesList);

        return view;
    }

    class TeamNamesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeamNamesAdapter.ViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

        private List<String> names;

        public List<String> getNames() {
            return names;
        }

        public TeamNamesAdapter(List<String> names) {
            this.names = names == null ? new ArrayList<String>() : names;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.team_names_list_item, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            String name = new ArrayList<>(names).get(position);
            holder.name.setText(name);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return names.size();
        }

        public void addName(String name) {
            if(names.contains(name) || name.isEmpty())
                return;

            names.add(name);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
            names.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                    Collections.swap(names, i, i + 1);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                    Collections.swap(names, i, i - 1);
                }
            }
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            CheckedTextView name;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                name = (CheckedTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_in_list);
                name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the call to `setRetainInstance` in the constructor, in `onCreateView` and in `onCreate`, but I still lose my RecyclerView items on rotation.

Is there any way to save those items and restore them on rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a `CustomDialogFragment` as well and `onSaveInstanceState` works fine.

You have some issues in your code: For example, during `onCreateView`, you always create a adapter using a null List. That's why your items disappear.

So, you have to add more code to save names during (`onSaveInstanceState`) and restore them during `onCreate` or `onCreateView`.

Something like:

```
public class TeamNamesEditDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);            
        savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("oldNames", (ArrayList<String>) adapter.getNames());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            ArrayList<String> previousNameList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("oldNames");
            adapter = new TeamNamesAdapter(previousNameList);
        } else {
            adapter = new TeamNamesAdapter(null);
        }
        ...
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: It always creates with null because i don't know how to save the state yet. When I will know, I will set the adapter. That is intentional. So basically what you're saying, is that the bundle that's saved in `onSaveInstanceState` is restored in `onCreateView`?

Comment: @GioraGuttsait I updated the answer. I tested. I could save the old List of names and restore them during onCreateView. And yes: During onCreate() and onCreateView(), android will pass the same saveInstanceState that you save during onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Awesome man, thanks a lot. I'm gonna check it in several hours and see if it works